# Javascript fetch returning whole HTML page and form data rather than just form data

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch-api

I am having an issue where when post form data using `fetch` and `FormData`. I end up getting a response showing the form data as well as the HTML of the page itself, as shown below.

[image: Output of fetch function]

```
let regForm = document.querySelector('.registration-form');
regForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    };
    fetch('register.php', options).then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    }).then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
});
```

From what I understand and have [researched](https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-with-fetch-in-vanilla-js/) I need to change the line where it says `return response.text();` to something along the lines of `return response.json();`. When I do that I get the error below. I am not sure if it's something with my form data or how I'm sending the data to the PHP file. **How can I get the response from the PHP file without getting all the HTML of the page along with it?**
[image: JS error]

Comment: This is how AJAX works, everything output from an HTTP request is returned. You can build a specialized PHP script to return only what you want. Your PHP is not returning JSON, so just changing the returned data type is not going to work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Any suggestions on how I might accomplish that?

Comment: What you're looking for is [_Content negotiation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) where your server-side code responds differently depending on various aspects of the request. Typically, you would use the `Accepts` header; normal requests _accept_ `text/html` but your AJAX (`fetch`) requests would send `Accepts: application/json` and then your script can use that to determine the appropriate response to send.

Comment: We are not able to see your `register.php` code that is generating too much text.

Comment: The issue ended up being some errors in the php file itself. It was an easy fix after I figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error I solved it by using String Interpolation. In your case it will be something like. You can add all the parameters you have.

```
let regForm = document.querySelector(".registration-form");
regForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
  };
  fetch(`register.php?Register${firsname}&${surname}&${email}`, options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```